# Accessing the css styles imported from a Lit module

Tags: javascript, css, lit

If I have a Lit module that exports css such as:

```
export const customStyles = css`
    ... styles ....
`;
```

And in my html I import these styles:

```
<script type="module">
    import { customStyles } from '@......LitModule.js';
</script>
```

Is it possible to then access these styles within the html?